# Is there a direct way to multiply a Size or Point by a number?

Tags: c#, .net

By "direct" I mean something like Size*2 (which doesn't work) as opposed to:

```
size1 = new Size(size1.Width * 2, size1.Height * 2);
```

Comment: @Joe, that's not multiplying which is what he asked for. The Size class provides static methods Add and Subtract, but nothing for direct multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can technically write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static Size Multiply(this Size size, double factor) {
        return new Size((int)(size.Width * factor), (int)(size.Height * factor));
    }
}
```

But just about nobody is going to use it correctly.  They'll write

```
this.Size.Multiply(1.2);
```

instead of the required

```
this.Size = this.Size.Multiply(1.2);
```

An almost inevitable mistake because it looks like an instance method.  So don't do it, just write a static helper method.

Comment: The extension method is better because it's more reusable and easier to discover than some helper method. Just call it MultipliedBy if you're worried about people using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can overload the * operator:

```
class Size 
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public Size(int w, int h)
    {
        this.Width = w;
        this.Height = h;
    }

    public static Size operator *(Size s, int n)
    {
        return new Size(s.Width * n, s.Height * n);
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Size s1 = new Size(1, 2);
Size s = s1 * 2; // s.Height = 2, s.Width = 4
```

Comment: @Steve: Perhaps the OP is using the built-in `Size` struct of .NET and not a class defined by him/her (which is not clear from the question). In the former case it's not possible to overload the * operator.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no * operator implemented for the [Size struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) you would have to create one. But with extension methods it is not possible to create new operators. Instead you could create an extension method called multiply for instance.

Comment: This assumes he is using System.Drawing.Size struct and not one of his own concoctions

Comment: I assumed he is using a class / struct that he is not allowed to change the original source code of. If it is his own class / struct, the answer would simply be to implement *operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not without work but it is quite easy to overload operators

see [demo of operator overloading on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28974/An-Introduction-to-Operator-Overloading-in-C)

see right at the bottom:

```
public static MySize operator +(MySize mySize, Int32 value)
{
    return new MySize(
        mySize.m_Width + value,
        mySize.m_Height + value);
}
```

It shouldn't take you long to work out the * operator overload

Comment: Except that Size is a struct, and structs cannot be the base of another struct or class, so it is not possible to subclass it for overloading the operator.

Comment: If your guess is correct that Size is from the .net class libs and not his own concoction then yes you are correct and short of a messy extension method he's scuppered